# Name or service not known при подключении к gitHub через SSH

Tags: git, github

Создал SSH-ключ, добавил его на GitHub, добавил настройки прокси в `.gitconfig`, но при проверке соединения выдаёт:

```
 $ ssh -T git@github.com
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблема в том, что `ssh` совершенно не интересует содержимое `.gitconfig`. И не должно интересовать.

Comment: 1. *SHH* — это опечатка? 2. какой протокол проксирует используемый вами *прокси*?

Comment: @kff через http тоже не пускает

Comment: @Николай К админу обратиться не пробовали? У Вас явно что-то хитрое с нестройками сети.

Comment: @kff сеть корпоративная, так что к админу не вариант, так как по идее нельзя этим пользоваться!

Answer (score 3):

> Could not resolve hostname github.com

перевод: «не могу преобразовать доменное имя github.com в ip-адрес».

проистекает это, скорее всего, из-за (временных) проблем в используемом вами ns-сервере.

попробуйте использовать любой из действующих в данный момент ip-адресов (вместо имени *github.com*):

```
192.30.252.128
192.30.252.129
192.30.252.130
192.30.252.131

192.30.252.148
192.30.252.149
192.30.252.150
192.30.252.151
```

пример:

```
$ ssh -T git@192.30.252.150
```

---

но раз в вашей сети используется прокси (скорее всего, это *http*-прокси), то, скорее всего, и порт 22 у вас будет заблокирован.

единственная надежда, что без вмешательства пропускаются пакеты, адресованные на порт 443 (обычно используется для общения по протоколу *https*).

для таких случаев у *github-овцев* [есть сервера, слушающие *ssh-подключения* на порту 443](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/). они доступны под доменным именем *ssh.github.com*.

если и это имя в вашей сети не резолвится, то можете воспользоваться ip-адресами (вторая группа из приведённого выше списка):

```
$ ssh -T -p 443 git@192.30.252.150
```

---

если «пробиться» через 443-й порт не вышло, и вы используете *gnu/linux* или **bsd*, то для очистки совести можно попробовать воспользоваться программой [*corkscrew*](https://www.opennet.ru/tips/1884_ssh_http_proxy_tunnel.shtml). хотя, по-моему, к успеху это вряд ли приведёт: такой трафик легко детектируется (а значит, и блокируется).

Comment: `$ ssh -T -p 443 git@192.30.252.150
ssh: connect to host 192.30.252.150 port 443: Connection timed out`

Comment: @Николай, значит, по ключу авторизоваться не получится.