# Зачем нужно при подключении Github'a заморачиваться с SSH-ключами, если можно без них?

Tags: visual-studio, git, github, ssh

Т.е. я делаю так в консоли Visual Studio Code.

```
git remote add origin ссылка на репозиторий

git push origin master
```

и

```
git pull origin master
```

Смысл использовать SSH?

И зачем нужно дополнение для GitHub? (применительно к Visual Studio Code).

И, например, собственный клиент от GitHub'a зачем в таком случае нужен?

Comment: как многолетний пользователь протокола ssh, задам недоуменный встречный вопрос: зачем городить эту муторнейшую мороку с логинами/паролями там, где без неё можно легко и безболезненно обойтись?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте HTTPS вместо SSH, и ключ не понадобятся.

Однако использовать ключ удобнее и безопаснее. Тому есть три причины:

1. Пароль используется исключительно для сверки с эталоном. SSH-ключ же опосредованно используется для шифрования всех данных, передаваемых по SSH-каналу.
2. Пароль используется в паре с логином, так как подтверждает, но не опознаёт пользователя. SSH-ключ же сам по себе является «логином» (точнее, не сам ключ, а его открытая часть, восстанавливаемая из закрытой и передаваемая на сервер).
3. Пароль как правило короткий (не более двадцати печатных символов). Типовая же закрытая часть SSH-ключа состоит из 2048 произвольных байт.

***P. S.:*** Как было верно замечено в комментариях, GitHub [рекомендует](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/) использовать не SSH, а именно HTTPS. Тому есть две причины:

1. *Порт для SSH может быть заблокирован межсетевым экраном; HTTPS же доступен везде.*
2. *Авторизация по ключу может быть перекрыта авторизацией «SAML single sign-on» (технология единого входа, используется на предприятиях), несовместимой с механизмом аутентификации GitHub-а.*

Comment: Интересно всё-таки почему же на самом GitHub использование подключение по HTTPS помечено как рекомендованное (https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)?

Comment: @АлександрТимофеев, обновил ответ.

Comment: *Порт для SSH может быть заблокирован* — см. [Using SSH over the HTTPS port](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/) и [мой ответ на другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489137/178576)