# Когда прописываю git push консоль зависает

Tags: git, github, git-push

Я начал изучать git. Попытался сделать push своего репозитория на github, но столкнулся с проблемой. После ввода команды "git push origin master" консоль зависает и больше ничего не происходит. Мне не предлагает авторизоваться, на github ничего не отправляется. Ждал долго, но результата никакого Как решить проблему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Фаервол может какой?.. https://www.githubstatus.com

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/489137/178576